# Open a file with spaces in the pathname

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use vscode (0.4.0) to open a file from the powershell commandline which has spaces in the path. Specifically the powershell profile, which lives under "My Documents"

I initially tried just:

```
code $PROFILE
```

but this just opens a file called "My" and does similar if I quote the file path:

```
code '\\myserver\myname\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'
code "\\myserver\myname\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1"
```

how do I go about opening a file from the commandline when it has spaces in the path?

I have also tested it on a local file "C:\temp\Test Spaces\foobar.txt" and it does similar, so it's not related to UNC

Comment: Does it work if you write `My\ Documents`?

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf: Sadly no it doesn't

Comment: Is this Windows or Mac?

Comment: @BenjaminPasero It is Windows

Comment: Have you tried using the [8.3 file name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) syntax?

Answer (score 3):

This seems strange, but I tried double quotes, and it worked:

```
code ""C:\test\test file.js""
```

Comment: Hmm, very odd.  That does work for me in cmd.exe but not in powershell, which is where I was originally trying to do it (I've edited the question to clarify this) - I've given you a +1 but I wonder what the workaround might be for powershell.  This is feeling a bit like some sort of bug with vscode.

Comment: Good workaround for now. I still logged an issue on our end to look into this.